# Calculation of duration between two timestamps in different rows

Tags: beginner, sql, mysql, datetime, database

In my sample data table below, all datatypes are varchar(255).

> ```
> |      event      |            timestamp           |       traceid       |
> | accepted        | 2016-01-16T09:35:48.653418931Z | AIP1452936948-44467 |
> | published_event | 2016-01-16T09:35:48.659767348Z | AIP1452936948-44467 |
> ```

Here is the expected output:

> ```
> |       traceid       | duration |
> | AIP1452936948-44467 |   108    |
> ```

And the code I would like reviewed...

```sql
select traceid, bUnixMS - aUnixMS as duration
from (
select 
a.traceid, 
CONVERT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(a.mydatetime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')), SIGNED) as aUnix, 
CONVERT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(b.mydatetime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')), SIGNED) as bUnix, 
(CONVERT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(a.mydatetime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')), SIGNED) + (CONVERT(LEFT(a.ms, 3), SIGNED) / 1000)) * 1000 as aUnixMS,
(CONVERT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(b.mydatetime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')), SIGNED) + (CONVERT(LEFT(b.ms, 3), SIGNED) / 1000)) * 1000 as bUnixMS,
CONVERT(LEFT(a.ms, 3), SIGNED) as aMS,
CONVERT(LEFT(b.ms, 3), SIGNED) as bMS

from (
   select
      event,
      traceid,
      CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(timestamp, 'T', 1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(timestamp, 'T', -1), '.', 1)) as mydatetime,  
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(timestamp, 'T', -1), '.', -1) as ms
   from applogs
   where event = "accepted"
) a

join (
   select
      event,
      traceid,
      CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(timestamp, 'T', 1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(timestamp, 'T', -1), '.', 1)) as mydatetime,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(timestamp, 'T', -1), '.', -1) as ms
   from applogs
   where event = "published_event"
) b on a.traceid = b.traceid
) as x
```

Comment: Why not JOIN the table to itself on `traceid` with `t1.event = 'accepted'` AND `t2.event = 'published'` ?

Comment: When refactored accordingly to your question, it seems I lose all performance and the query executes seemingly "forever". There is ~349k rows so I can't off the top of my head explain why this would happen.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `traceid` and `event`?

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving enough details (such as specific table structure, index, volume, types of queries, etc.) nor your constraints.

Nor do you explain how you come with value `108`.

So my answer supposes you have only two timestamps per `traceid` and that the events are ordered logically in the same order as the timestamps.

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND,
    STR_TO_DATE(MIN(`timestamp`), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S.%fZ'),
    STR_TO_DATE(MAX(`timestamp`), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S.%fZ'))
FROM applogs
GROUP BY traceid
```

This gives you `6319` which is a number of microseconds between the two. No idea on how you come to `108` from there. Note that it works only if you change your values to have only 6 digits after the dot, as the parser searches for microseconds. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3554/8/0) and the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

If you really need your sub microseconds format you will need to split the string in two, first part being what is used above and last part being the last 3 digits as fractions of microseconds. And then add all of it.

This begs to ask why you are storing such a timestamp in a text field, this is not a good design. That would be the main point of the review: change your model and do not store timestamps in text fields, use the appropriate types of your RDBMS.

PS: since `timestamp` is the name of a type I do not recommend naming your column with it. Also, on the modeling part, your structure seems to reflect a key-value pattern, which is not always a good idea in RDBMS.